# Parse 1 column into 3 columns using DB2 SQL

Tags: sql, db2

Using DB2 for z/OS 10, I'm have a column (ADDRESS3) in a table that contains city, state, and zipcode all in one column. But, the formatting is somewhat "free-form". (see code below)

I can successfully parse the city by taking everything before the comma. Using only DB2 SQL, how would I parse out the state and zipcode?

```
SELECT ADDRESS3,
       TRIM(SUBSTR(ADDRESS3,1,LOCATE(',', ADDRESS3)-1)) AS CITY
  FROM MYTABLE

ADDRESS3                            CITY         
----------------------------------  -------------
GRANADA HILLS       ,CA 91344       GRANADA HILLS
SIMI VALLEY         ,CA 93065       SIMI VALLEY  
BUENA PARK          ,CA 90621       BUENA PARK   
SHERMAN OAKS        ,CA 91423       SHERMAN OAKS 
GLENDALE            ,CA 91203-2089  GLENDALE     
VENTURA             ,CA 93002       VENTURA      
HAWTHORNE           ,CA 90250       HAWTHORNE    
PASADENA            ,CA 91185-2594  PASADENA     
BEVERLY HILLS       ,CA 90211       BEVERLY HILLS
ARCADIA             ,CA 91007       ARCADIA      
WALNUT CREEK        ,CA 94596       WALNUT CREEK 
INDEPENDANCE        ,CA 93526       INDEPENDANCE 
LOS ANGELES         ,CA 90017       LOS ANGELES
```

Ultimately, I'd like the query results to look like this:

```
CITY          STATE ZIP
------------- ----- -----
GRANADA HILLS CA    91344
SIMI VALLEY   CA    93065
BUENA PARK    CA    90621
SHERMAN OAKS  CA    91423
GLENDALE      CA    91203
VENTURA       CA    93002
HAWTHORNE     CA    90250
PASADENA      CA    91185
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, if the state is 2 chars and zip 5 chars:

```
SELECT 
  ADDRESS3,
  TRIM(SUBSTR(ADDRESS3, 1, LOCATE(',', ADDRESS3)-1)) AS CITY,
  TRIM(SUBSTR(ADDRESS3, LOCATE(',', ADDRESS3) + 1), 2) AS STATE,
  TRIM(SUBSTR(ADDRESS3, LOCATE(',', ADDRESS3) + 4), 5) AS ZIP
FROM MYTABLE
```

Comment: Thanks, forpas! You nailed it!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this assuming the format is the same always.

```
  SELECT 
       TRIM(
         SUBSTR(
           SUBSTR(MYTABLE.A, LOCATE(',', MYTABLE.A) + 1)
           , 1
           , POSITION(' ' , SUBSTR(MYTABLE.A, LOCATE(',', MYTABLE.A) + 1))
         )
       ) AS STATE
    ,  TRIM(
           SUBSTR(
             SUBSTR(MYTABLE.A, LOCATE(',', MYTABLE.A) + 1)
           , POSITION(' ' , SUBSTR(MYTABLE.A, LOCATE(',', MYTABLE.A) + 1))
         ) 
       ) AS ZIP
  FROM MYTABLE
```

The demo result into these results with these values

**Test data**

```
  VALUES
    ('GRANADA HILLS       ,CA 91344')
  , ('SIMI VALLEY         ,CA 93065') 
  , ('GLENDALE            ,CA 91203-2089')
  , ('SIMI VALLEY         ,CA    93065')  
  , ('SIMI VALLEY         ,CA    93065') 
  , ('GLENDALE            ,CA    91203-2089')
```

**Results**

```
STATE   ZIP
CA      91344
CA      93065
CA      91203-2089
CA      93065
CA      93065
CA      91203-2089
```

see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=09580db1e4e256aae082a80bce0b7831)

Comment: Thanks, Raymond! When I run your code, I get

"The number of arguments specified for scalar function 'POSITION' is invalid."

But, I understand what you're getting at.

Answer (score 0):

interestingly, this worked, too.

```
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTR(ADDRESS3, 1, locate(',', ADDRESS3) - 1)) AS city,
       SUBSTR(TRIM(SUBSTR(ADDRESS3, locate(',', ADDRESS3) + 1)), 1, 2) state,
       SUBSTR(TRIM(SUBSTR(TRIM(SUBSTR(ADDRESS3, locate(',', ADDRESS3) + 1)), 3)), 1, 5) zip
  FROM MyTable
```